# Firefox doesn't open google on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, firefox

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Lenovo ideapad 520-15IKB and since it is installed, firefox doesn't work. It doesn't open google.com via the normal wifi network.

I installed Chromium and it works perfectly. I uninstalled firefox and downloaded from firefox webpage it self and installed and still nothing.

It works only if I'm connected to VPN or if I use my mobile phone as a wifi hot spot. I never encountered such a strange error. I really tried everything I found on the web and did a lot of research. All firefox settings are fine, I check the proxy settings and they are fine. I tried in firefox safe mode and still same issue, I refreshed it, still same issue, cleared cache and cookies and still same issue, uninstalled it and removed all of its folders and still same issue, I even reinstalled the OS and still nothing. I also tried creating another user and logged through it and still same issue.

Network setting on the unbuntu seems 100%. Any other browser works fine, but I need firefox specifically. My ubuntu also is up to date and no more updates available.

I really don't understand why this is happening!

lastly I installed older versions of Firefox like 101, 115, 117 and still same issue. currently I have the latest version 118.0.1

Anyone else faced this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Try a new Profile for Firefox `firefox -P`